# Prototype Add Class to Class

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a few div's like this in my page:

```
<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing">
```

I would like to append a class to the div when I hover over it then remove it when I mouseout?

How can this be done with prototype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that with prototype, and not use standard CSS for that?

```
div.listing-type-list.catalog-listing:hover { additional CSS goes here }
```

This won't work in IE6, but there is [htc file](http://www.xs4all.nl/~peterned/csshover.html) for that. You would not be able to select the div via `getElementsByClassName` in javascript, if that was your intention.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="listing-type-list catalog-listing"
 onmouseover="Element.toggleClassName(this, 'newClass')" 
 onmouseout="Element.toggleClassName(this, 'newClass')" >
```